# Difference between converting int to char by (char) and by ASCII

Tags: c++, char

I have an example:

```
int var = 5;
char ch = (char)var;
char ch2 = var+48;
cout << ch << endl;
cout << ch2 << endl;
```

I had some other code. (char) returned wrong answer, but +48 didn't. When I changed **ONLY** (char) to +48, then my code got corrected.

What is the difference between converting int to char by using (char) and +48 (ASCII) in C++?

Comment: `(char) 5` gives you a `char` with ASCII 5 value.

Comment: The ASCII code of the character `0` is 48. So if you have the number `5` and you want to get the _character_ `5` you need to add the 48. If you just prepend `(char)` to your number `5`, you get a ther `char` whose ASCII code is 5. BTW don't write `48`, but rather `'0'` which is the same thing but more readable.

Comment: I find hexadecimal a better method for representing ASCII.  For example, 0x41 is 'A' and 0x61 is 'a', they are hex 0x20 apart.  Symbols start at hex 0x20 and the numbers at 0x30.

Comment: Wow. There are sooo many misconceptions going on here all at once. I suppose that makes it a good question. You will learn something new today, OP.

Answer (score 1):

`char ch=(char)var;` has the same effect as `char ch=var;` and assigns the numeric value `5` to `ch`. You're using ASCII (supported by all modern systems) and ASCII character code 5 represents Enquiry 'ENQ' an old terminal control code. Perhaps some old timer has a clue what it did!

`char ch2 = var+48;` assigns the numeric value `53` to `ch2` which happens to represent the ASCII character for the digit '5'. ASCII 48 is zero (0) and the digits all appear in the ASCII table in order after that. So 48+5 lands on 53 (which represents the character '5').

In C++ `char` is a integer type. The value is interpreted as representing an ASCII character but it should be thought of as holding a number.

Its numeric range is either [-128,127] or [0,255]. That's because C++ requires `sizeof(char)==1` and all modern platforms have 8 bit bytes.

NB: C++ doesn't actually mandate ASCII, but again that will be the case on all modern platforms.

PS: I think its an unfortunate artifact of C (inherited by C++) that `sizeof(char)==1` and there isn't a separate fundamental type called `byte`.

Comment: BTW, *modern* systems are now supporting Unicode.  ASCII has been around for a very long time.

Comment: Also, you can have other encodings on *modern* computers.  A *modern* computer doesn't imply ASCII.  The Apple II supported ASCII.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews True. Many platforms are actually using `char` for UTF-8 (because that's the only Unicode encoding that will fit an 8-bit byte). But I don't want to get too technical here. My point is really that on any modern platform 53 will be '5'. For example, I'm not aware of any modern platform using EBCDIC where '5' is code point 245.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that casting to char `(char)` explicitly converts the digit to a `char` and adding 48 do not.

Its important to note that an `int` is typically 32 bit and `char` is typically 8 bit. This means that the number you can store in a char is from -127 to +127(or 0 to 255-(2^8-1) if you use unsigned char) and in an `int` from  −2,147,483,648 (−231) to 2,147,483,647 (231 − 1)(or 0 to 2^32 -1 for unsigned).

Adding 48 to a value is not changing the type to char.

Comment: Reminder:  there are 3 kinds of `char`:  *unsigned*, *signed* and `char`.  Your example shows `signed char`.  The type of `char` is implementation defined.

Answer (score 0):

Generally `char` represents a number as `int` does. Casting an `int` value to `char` doesn't provide it's ASCII representation.

The ASCII codes as numbers for digits range from `48` (== `'0'`) to `58` (== `'9'`). So to get the printable digit you have to add `'0'` (or `48`).

Comment: Always prefer the character literal, e.g. '0', to the ASCII value (decimal or hex).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Sure.

Answer (score 0):

A `char` is simply the base integral denomination in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). Output statements, like `cout` and `printf` map `char` integers to the corresponding character mapping. On Windows computers this is typically [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Note that the 5<sup>th</sup> in ASCII maps to the Enquiry character which has no printable character, while the 53<sup>rd</sup> character maps to the printable character 5.

A generally accepted hack to store a number 0-9 in a `char` is to do: `const char ch = var + '0'` It's important to note the shortcomings here:

1. If your code is running on some non-ASCII character mapping then characters 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9 may not be laid out in order in which case this wouldn't work
2. If `var` is outside the 0 - 9 range this `var + '0'` will map to something other than a numeric character mapping

A guaranteed way to get the most significant digit of a number independent of **1** or **2** is to use:

```
const auto ch = to_string(var).front()
```